# NestJS - loops endlessly when starting in watch mode

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

This is a very simple question and yet I could not find answers anywhere, hopefully here:
I'm trying to run the default NestJS project by using:

```
npm run start:dev
```

The command I used to create the project is:

```
nest new project-name
```

The result is:

```
[18:43:12] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[18:43:18] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

In a loop over and over endlessly...

It's important to say I didn't change ANYTHING in the default project and this was replicated on multiple computers with Windows 10 and Windows 11.

The NodeJS version I'm using is 18.13.0 and the NestJS version I'm using is 9.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

What is your npm version?
Try to downgrade to version 6.x.x